# Finding rows that do not have a corresponding entry in join table

Tags: sql, sqlite, activerecord

I have a table A that is joined to another table B through a join-table J. How can I access all the rows from table A that do not have a corresponding "join" entry in J based on a given attribute from table B? For example:

```
Table A:
-------
id

Table J:
-------
A_id
B_id

Table B:
-------
id
name
```

Say that for a given B.name = "Suzie", how can we determine all the rows A that do not have an entry in J with B_id where B.name = "Suzie"? I feel like this should be a simple query, and I considered using `GROUP BY` because it seems that for each entry in A, you want to determine if the B_id that you're working with (where B.name = "Suzie" in this case) exists in J for each "group" of A_id's. Somehow, I can't wrap my head around this; would appreciate a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
Select  A.*
From    TableA  A
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  1
    From    TableJ  J
    Join    TableB  B   On  B.id = J.B_id
    Where   J.A_id = A.id
    And     B.Name = 'Suzie'
)
```

Comment: I think its better to write `SELECT 1` when using `EXISTS()` as it is more clear that the columns from the inner select are not needed anywhere.

Comment: True, that does remove some ambiguity with `EXISTS` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe another way to do this would be to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the join table, but with another `ON` condition that `J.b_id` is the `b.id` for the desired "name". Therefore, you are able to retrieve all items in `A` that do or do not have a corresponding `B` item.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN J 
ON J.a_id = a.id AND J.b_id IN
  (SELECT id FROM B where B.name "Suzie")
WHERE J.a_id IS NULL
```

Would be curious as to any thoughts about performance?